Apache Camel DeadLetterChannel unable to capture JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData while writing to the Dead Letter Queue
Given below is the code snippet to write an error on DLQ when some exception has occurred.
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("jms:queue:" + this.dlq+"?allowAdditionalHeaders=*")
                .onExceptionOccurred(exchange -> {
                    Exception exception = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
                    boolean shouldRouteToDLQ = false;
                    int reasonCode = MQException.MQRC_NONE;
                    Throwable cause = exception;
                    while (cause != null) {
                        if (cause instanceof MQException) {
                            MQException mqException = (MQException) cause;
                            if (mqException.reasonCode == MQException.MQRC_Q_FULL ||
                                    mqException.reasonCode == MQException.MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME || mqException.reasonCode == MQException.MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN) {
                                reasonCode = mqException.reasonCode;
                                shouldRouteToDLQ = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        cause = cause.getCause();
                    }

                    if (shouldRouteToDLQ) {
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_FORMAT, MQConstants.MQFMT_DEAD_LETTER_HEADER );
                        // Retrieve the current endpoint from headers
                        String currentQueue = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CurrentQueue", String.class);
                        String currentQueueManager = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CurrentQueueManager", String.class);
                        log.info("Current queue {} Current QueueManager {}", currentQueue, currentQueueManager);
                        MQDLH mqdlh = new MQDLH();
                        mqdlh.setCodedCharSetId(1208); // Set to match the MQ Manager's CCSID (UTF-8)
                        mqdlh.setEncoding(MQConstants.MQENC_NATIVE); // Use native encoding

                        log.info("Reason Code" + reasonCode);
                        mqdlh.setReason(MQConstants.MQRC_Q_FULL);
                        mqdlh.setDestQName(currentQueue.replace(".ERROR","")); //For simulation
                        mqdlh.setDestQMgrName(currentQueueManager);
                        mqdlh.setPutApplName(appName);
                        mqdlh.setFormat(MQConstants.MQFMT_STRING);
                        mqdlh.setPutDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date()));
                        mqdlh.setPutTime(new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmssSS").format(new Date()).substring(0, 8));

                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
                        mqdlh.write(dos);
                        byte[] mqdlhBytes = baos.toByteArray();

                        log.info("CCSID: " + mqdlh.getCodedCharSetId());
                        log.info("Encoding: " + mqdlh.getEncoding());

                        log.info("MQ DLH String: " + new String(mqdlhBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        // For debugging: Print the byte array of the MQDLH header
                        log.info("MQDLH Bytes: " + Arrays.toString(mqdlhBytes));

                        // Check the reason code bytes within the header
                        byte[] reasonCodeBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(MQException.MQRC_Q_FULL).array();
                        log.info("Reason Code Bytes: " + Arrays.toString(reasonCodeBytes));

                        // Verify reason code bytes in MQDLH
                        byte[] reasonCodeBytes2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(mqdlhBytes, 8, 12);
                        log.info("Reason Code Bytes in MQDLH: {}", Arrays.toString(reasonCodeBytes2));

                        byte[] bodyBytes = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                        // Ensure the body is correctly converted to bytes
                        String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                        log.info("Original message body: {}", body);
                        byte[] bodyBytes2 = body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        log.info("Body Bytes: " + Arrays.toString(bodyBytes));

                        byte[] combinedMessage = new byte[mqdlhBytes.length + bodyBytes.length];
                        System.arraycopy(mqdlhBytes, 0, combinedMessage, 0, mqdlhBytes.length);
                        System.arraycopy(bodyBytes, 0, combinedMessage, mqdlhBytes.length, bodyBytes.length);
                        log.info("Combined Bytes: " + Arrays.toString(combinedMessage));
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(combinedMessage);

                        log.info("Logging JMS Headers {} ", exchange.getIn().getHeaders().toString());
                        // Set encoding and CCSID in JMS headers if needed
                        exchange.getIn().setHeaders(exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("appIdentity","VOS");
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("example","value");
                        //exchange.getIn().setHeader("JMS_IBM_MQMD_example","JMS_IBM_MQMD_value");
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("CurrentQueue",currentQueue.replace(".ERROR",""));
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_APPLIDENTITYDATA, "VOS");
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_PUTAPPLNAME, "VOSAPP");
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("JMS_IBM_Encoding", MQConstants.MQENC_NATIVE);
                        log.info("Logging JMS Headers after setting encoding {} ", exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
                        exchange.setProperty("FAILURE_ROUTE_TO_DLQ", true);
                        log.info("Headers {} Body {}",exchange.getIn().getHeaders(), new String(exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        log.error("MQ Error Occured. Message will be sent to DLQ. Headers {} Message Body {} Error {}",exchange.getIn().getHeaders(), new String(exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class),StandardCharsets.UTF_8), dlq, exception);

                    } else {
                        log.error("For Route Id {} Headers {} and Message {} An error occurred: {}", exchange.getFromRouteId(),exchange.getIn().getHeaders(),exchange.getIn().getBody(), exception.getMessage());
                        exchange.setProperty("FAILURE_ROUTE_TO_DLQ", false);
                    }
                })
                .onPrepareFailure(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        log.info("Message before DLQ: " + exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
                    }
                })
                .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                .redeliveryDelay(1000)
                .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
                .onRedelivery(exchange -> {
                    if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(exchange.getProperty("FAILURE_ROUTE_TO_DLQ"))) {
                        // If not routing to DLQ, handle the redelivery differently, e.g., log and stop redelivery
                        log.error("Redelivery stopped due to non-MQ specific error");
                        throw new Exception("Redelivery stopped due to non-MQ specific error. Message: "+exchange.getIn().getBody());
                    }
                })
                .logHandled(true)
        );

Given below is my log output in which I can see that JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData is being set properly in the headers.
Message before DLQ: {appIdentity=HENRY, CamelMessageTimestamp=1723465932100, CurrentQueue=EXAMPLE.ISB.HENRY.ISO, CurrentQueueManager=EXAMPLE.DEV.QMGR, example=value, JMS_IBM_Character_Set=ISO-8859-1, JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, JMS_IBM_Format=MQDEAD  , JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData=HENRY, JMS_IBM_MQMD_PutApplName=HENRYAPP, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=6, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20240812, JMS_IBM_PutTime=12321210, JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSCorrelationIDAsBytes=null, JMSDeliveryMode=1, JMSDestination=null, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:414d51204750502e4445562e514d47526ecab96608879521, JMSPriority=0, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=null, JMSTimestamp=1723465932100, JMSType=null, JMSXAppID=swx                         , JMSXDeliveryCount=1, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=EXAMPLE         }

Problem: I see all the headers are getting populated properly except for JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData when I view this message in the IBM MQ Explorer.
Screenshot:

How to resolve this issue?

What you have shown is the Explorer can't see anything in JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData, but if you browse / read the message in anyother way, is the field set correctly?

Why is the close vote ?

@chughts It isnt getting written to DLQ. I checked using MQ utility as well.

Just to clarify, the message has the JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData, but once on the DLQ it doesn't ?

How to test this?

Just to clarify, the message has the JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData, but once on the DLQ it doesn't ?  --- Thats Right

I get it. But how to test it locally?

After onPrepareFailure where the call is going?

The logic which runs after onPrepareFailure is removing that particular header.

@AnishB. which logic are you talking about ? The onPrepareFailure is only for logging, even when I remove that section nothing happens.

There is not much info on what issue are you facing. Are you setting the headers again?

No I am not, The logs are of moment before message is written to DLQ

There are 8 fields of the MQMD structure that are special and require authorization:
Origin Context:

PutApplType
PutApplName
PutDate
PutTime
ApplOriginData

Identity Context:

UserIdentifier
AccountingToken
ApplIdentityData

Before using any of these MQMD fields, you need to tell MQ that your code will be setting/updating these fields and MQ will then check if you have permission to do what you want to do.
You can read about it in the IBM MQ documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=application-jms-message-object-properties

I dont get any authorization error on the MQ logs

For Origin & Context Identity fields, there are no error messages written to a log file. The field just does not change which is what you are complaining about. Read the link I gave you and follow it then you will be able to update the ApplIdentityData field of the MQMD structure. I have written many C and Java MQ applications that modify/update the Origin/Context Identity fields. Just follow the instructions and it will work.

I went through the documentation and I am not sure about how to set the property if my code is written using Apache Camel

As indicated in the link provided by @Roger, try defining the property WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT to either WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT or WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT in your onExceptionOccurred code block, it is defined in WMQConstants. You may need to define the boolean property WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED to a true value in advance as well. By the way, why don't you set these properties in onPrepareFailure, in this method you are sure that the message will be sent to the DLQ, I think it is clear, although this fact doesn't change the proposed solution.

Can you give me the code snippet. I am unsure where to set these properties.

According to IBM MQ Documentation,

To set JMS_IBM_MQMD_APPLIDENTITYDATA, you need to set this
WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT property with WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT value.

For code written with Apache Camel, you need to set these properties (WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED & WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT) via Exchange object which is given below:
exchange.setProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
exchange.setProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT, WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT);

Ref:

Reading and writing the message descriptor from an IBM MQ classes for JMS application
JMS destination object properties
JavaDoc For Apache Camel's Exchange Interface

